# Not able to run portable chrome .desktop opening in text editor

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, google-chrome, launcher

I installed portable chrome using https://github.com/shivamgly/Google-Chrome-Portable-maker-for-linux  this link I am not able to run this chrome. Chrome.desktop file opens in text-editor.

Screenshot of install folder:

[image: screenshot of install folder in Nautilus]

.desktop file code

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Chrome Portable
Type=Application
Exec=sh -c 'if [ `ls -ial "$(dirname "$*")"/data/chrome-sandbox | cut -d\  -f4,5 | sed -r "s/ /:/g"` != root:root ]; then echo "sudo chown root:root data/chrome-sandbox\nsudo chmod 4755 data/chrome-sandbox\nrm -f execute_this.sh\nenv HOME=\"\$(dirname \"\$*\")\"/data/VHOME data/launcher >/dev/null 2>&1 &" > "$(dirname "$*")"/execute_this.sh; fi; if [ `ls -ial "$(dirname "$*")"/data/chrome-sandbox | cut -d\  -f2` != -rwsr-xr-x ]; then echo "sudo chown root:root data/chrome-sandbox\nsudo chmod 4755 data/chrome-sandbox\nrm -f execute_this.sh\nenv HOME=\"\$(dirname \"\$*\")\"/data/VHOME data/launcher >/dev/null 2>&1 &" > "$(dirname "$*")"/execute_this.sh; fi; env HOME="$(dirname "$*")"/data/VHOME "$(dirname "$*")"/data/launcher' dummy %k
Icon=google-chrome
```

Comment: All that script in a .desktop file seems suspicious. The github author's claim that the "sandbox must be owned by root" also seems suspect.

Comment: You need to add the `.desktop` file to your applications directory so it will show up as an icon, but I don't think you should. Like @user535733 , I think this looks rather suspicious.  I'd be interested to see the contents of `execute_this.sh`  - please [edit] your question and add it.